# More than 1 modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have this modal, and would like to make many of them on the same page. I tried a lot, but nope. Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Here the code:

HTML

```
<div  class="containerofelements">
 <div id="s2-01" class="resizeratio">1.00</div>
  <div id="s-wrap" class="wrap" style="transform: scale(0.04);">
   <div class="elements" style="transform: scale(0.04);">
     <div id="s-rr"class="resizeratio">0.04</div>
      <div id="s-001" class="slider16" midicc="1, 80" colour="#ff3300"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.containerofelements {
}
.resizeratio  {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
  color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
.wrap {
  background-color: rgba(0, 80, 128, 1);
  transform-origin: 1880px 0;
}
.elements {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 800px;
  transform-origin: 1880px 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".resizeratio").click(function() {
 var el = $('.elements');
  var scale = $(this).text();
   el.css({
    transform: "scale(" + scale + ")"
  });
 });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".resizeratio").click(function() {
  var el = $('.wrap');
  var scale = $(this).text();
   el.css({
    transform: "scale(" + scale + ")"
  });
 });
});
```

I tried to apply separate names, IDs, but no good results without replicating everything which is not a good practice I suppose, a waste of code.

Comment: please show what you have tried. it help us understand what you miss, instead of writting code for you (which is not welcome here anyway).

Comment: Hi John! I'm not sure about our wanted effect: do you want the modals next to each other or do you want one showing after each other, only one active at a time?

Comment: Hi Magelan, the modal opens with a button. i need to have many buttons, each of them will open a different modal.

Comment: i tried adding IDs, differentiate names, nothing works